# Validación Regex en visual basic.net

Tags: jquery, vb.net, regex, visual-studio-2017

Estoy haciendo un formulario de registro y hasta ahora voy validando el campo DNI y CORREO. El problema es con el campo CORREO ya que en el javascript lo deja pasar porque esta bien, pero en el visual basic.net NO LO DEJA PASAR. Yo me doy cuenta si pasaron o no pasaron los datos por los "alerts" de mis validaciones en el javascript; además no me aparece ningún alert que diga que esta mal, por eso digo que en el javascript evalúa y lo deja pasar pero en el visual basic evalua Y NO LO DEJA PASAR.

**Botón Registrar**

```
Protected Sub btnRegistrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrar.Click

Dim validar_DNI As Regex = New Regex("/^[0-9]+$/")
Dim validar_correo As Regex = New Regex("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/")

If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
            Return
        Else
            If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Length <> 8 Then
                Return
            Else
                If validar_DNI.IsMatch(txtDNI.Text) Then
                    Return
                Else
                    If txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
                        Return
                    Else
                        If Not txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Length >= 11 Then
                            Return
                        Else
                            If Not txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Length <= 60 Then
                                Return
                            Else
                                If Not validar_correo.IsMatch(txtCorreo.Text) Then
                                    Return
                                Else

                                    Try

                                        Dim clRegistrar As New SIMULADOR_LOG.clsExamenLOG
                                        Dim User As New SIMULADOR_ENT.clsUsuarioSim
                                        With User
                                            .dni_user = Integer.Parse(txtDNI.Text)
                                            .ape_pat_user = txtApellidoPaterno.Text
                                            .ape_mat_user = txtApellidoMaterno.Text
                                            .nombre_user = txtNombres.Text
                                            .direccion_user = txtDireccion.Text
                                            .celular_user = txtCelular.Text
                                            .correo_user = txtCorreo.Text
                                            .dept_user = cmbDepartamento.Text
                                            .prov_user = cmbProvincia.Text
                                            .dist_user = cmbDistrito.Text
                                            .fech_nacimiento = txtFechaNacimiento.Text
                                        End With

                                        Dim mensajeLog As String = clRegistrar.RegistrarUsuario(User)

                                        Dim Mensaje As String = "<script type=""text/javascript"">" &
                                                                "Message('El sistema dice: " & mensajeLog & "')</script>"

                                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "msg", Mensaje)

                                        Response.Redirect("SimuladorExamen.aspx")

                                    Catch

                                    End Try

                                End If
                            End If
                            End If
                    End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
End Sub
```

**Validacion_registrar.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#form1").submit(function () {

        //===========================DNI==================================

        //#<%=txtDNI.ClientID%>

        if ($("#txtDNI").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'DNI'");
            return false;
        }

        var reg = /^[0-9]+$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtDNI").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese solo números en el campo 'DNI'");
            return false;
        }

        if ($("#txtDNI").val().trim().length != 8) {
            alert("Su DNI debe ser 8 números");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================APELLIDO PATERNO==================================

        if ($("#txtApellidoPaterno").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Apellido Paterno'");
            return false;
        }

        var reg = /^[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú][a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+(\s+[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú]?[a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+)*$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtApellidoPaterno").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese solo letras en el campo 'Apellido Paterno'");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtApellidoPaterno").val().trim().length <= 60)) {
            alert("Su Apellido paterno debe ser menos de 60 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtApellidoPaterno").val().trim().length >= 3)) {
            alert("Su Apellido paterno debe ser más de 3 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================APELLIDO MATERNO==================================

        if ($("#txtApellidoMaterno").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Apellido Materno'");
            return false;
        }

        //var reg = /^[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z][a-záéíóú]+(\s+[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]?[a-záéíóú]+)*$/;
        var reg = /^[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú][a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+(\s+[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú]?[a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+)*$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtApellidoMaterno").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese solo letras en el campo 'Apellido Materno'");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtApellidoMaterno").val().trim().length <= 60)) {
            alert("Su Apellido Materno debe ser menos de 60 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtApellidoMaterno").val().trim().length >= 3)) {
            alert("Su Apellido Materno debe ser más de 3 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================NOMBRE COMPLETO==================================

        if ($("#txtNombres").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Nombres'");
            return false;
        }

        var reg = /^[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú][a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+(\s+[ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z|a-záéíóú]?[a-záéíóú|ÁÉÍÓÚA-Z]+)*$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtNombres").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese solo letras en el campo 'Nombres'");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtNombres").val().trim().length <= 60)) {
            alert("Su Nombre debe ser menos de 60 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtNombres").val().trim().length >= 2)) {
            alert("Su Nombre debe ser más de 2 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================DIRECCION COMPLETA==================================

        if ($("#txtDireccion").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Dirección'");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtDireccion").val().trim().length <= 200)) {
            alert("Su Dirección debe ser menos de 200 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtDireccion").val().trim().length >= 10)) {
            alert("Su Dirección debe ser más de 10 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================NUMERO DE CELULAR==================================

        if ($("#txtCelular").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Celular'");
            return false;
        }

        var reg = /^[0-9]+$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtCelular").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese solo números en el campo 'Celular'");
            return false;
        }

        if ($("#txtCelular").val().trim().length != 9) {
            alert("Su celular debe ser 9 números");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================CORREO ELECTRONICO==================================

        if ($("#txtCorreo").val().trim().length == 0) {
            alert("Te falta el campo 'Correo'");
            return false;
        }

        var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

        if (!(reg.test($("#txtCorreo").val().trim()))) {
            alert("Ingrese un correo válido en el campo 'Correo Electrónico'");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtCorreo").val().trim().length <= 60)) {
            alert("Su Correo debe ser menos de 60 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        if (!($("#txtCorreo").val().trim().length >= 11)) {
            alert("Su Correo debe ser más de 11 caractéres");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================DEPARTAMENTO==================================

        if ($("#cmbDepartamento").val() == 0) {
            alert("Te falta escoger el 'Departamento'");
            return false;
        }

        ////===========================PROVINCIA==================================

        if ($("#cmbProvincia").val() == 0) {
            alert("Te falta escoger el 'Provincia'");
            return false;
        }

        //===========================DISTRITO==================================

        if ($("#cmbDistrito").val() == 0) {
                alert("Te falta escoger el 'Distrito'");
                return false;
        }



    });

});
```

Comment: si mi apellido es güiraldes funciona? Igual, tene en cuenta que las reges pueden variar de lenguaje en lenguaje. y toda esa sucesion de if..else... es fea.. para que hacer el else, si al entrar al if haces return?

Comment: si mi correo es de la oficina tampoco lo puedo usar?

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que pongo el return porque de lo contrario el flujo continua, si te das cuenta hay un "Response.Redirect("SimuladorExamen.aspx")", cuando el usuario le de click en "Registrar" de inmediato se irá a la otra página sin que se haya validado bien.

Comment: solo es para gmail y hotmail.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que una parte es en javascript para que me muestre los alerts y otra parte es el en el visual basic.net. En el visual basic.net estoy obligado hacerlo por el flujo como te comente (para que se detenga y no siga ejecutando más) y el javascript para mostrarle al usuario en donde le falta validar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok. tu regex esta mal...

lo que deberias tener del lado de vb es:

```
Dim validar_correo As Regex = New Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@(hotmail|gmail)[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$")
```

Igual, como nota al margen, ni los nombres, ni los telefonos, ni los datos personales se validan con regex...

Que pasa si una persona se llama àmaira? no estas validando ese acento.

Lo que se valida, es que sean cosas logicas (nombres sin numeros por ejemplo), pero no una precision exacta de la validación.

Y lo que decis del flujo, tambien es incorrecto. Esto:

```
If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
        Return
    Else
        If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Length <> 8 Then
            Return
        Else
            If validar_DNI.IsMatch(txtDNI.Text) Then
                Return
            Else
                If txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
                    Return
                Else
                    If Not txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Length >= 11 Then
                        Return
                    Else
```

Es lo mismo que esto:

```
If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
    Return
end if
If txtDNI.Text.Trim.Length <> 8 Then
    Return
end if
If validar_DNI.IsMatch(txtDNI.Text) Then
    Return
end if
If txtCorreo.Text.Trim.Equals("") Then
    Return
end if
etc....
```

ya que cada return termina el flujo y hace que la funcion termine

Comment: Gracias amigo, pero ahora tengo un problema con el DNI, le quite esos back slash y NO ME FUNCIONO :( , y si le vuelvo a poner los back slash NADA TAMPOCO.

Comment: no deberias usar una regex para validar el dni. alcanza con controlar que sea un numero. @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia pero ¿como podrías validarlo diciendo que si son numeros y no son numeros?

Comment: por ejemplo, tratando de convertirlo a numero ;) @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal

Comment: Si te refieres al Integer.parse te capte la idea, pero como podria ponerlo acá: " If Integer.parse(txtDNI.Text...)... Then"

Comment: usa tryparse ;) @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal